# Will ferrite cores reduce the surge on the 5V line?

Tags: microcontroller, filter, emi-filtering

I think my ATMEGA AVR MCU is malfunctioning due to 5 VDC line surge.

The MCU is installed in a factory and the power line is very noisy.

I captured the 5VDC line. There were high frequency (10 MHz) 13 V peak ringing waves.

If I install ferrite core for each line and 2 wires together, will it be effective?

What type of capacitors are effective?

**[image: surge at 5vdc line]

Comment: Is this an AVR module you bought online or did you build something around an AVR uController yourself?

Comment: which ferrite and how/where would you "install" it. You should add a schematic of the power supply section. Otherwise this will be wild guesswork

Comment: So you get a 5V supply directly from factory network?

Comment: I think that "very noisy" is kind of an understatement for a peak that is > 250% of the nominal voltage.

Comment: You can review typical conducted immunity circuits to protect against EFT. This is typically a mixture of 1) some large cap 2) some smaller ceramic cap 3) a TVS.

Comment: Be suspicious of your 'scope probing in a "very noisy" environment...what appears on the screen may be misleading you.

Comment: The board is made by a company. And our factory is very noisy environmental. Noise cut transformer is installed at scope power.

Comment: Please show your probe setup. _"I think my ATMEGA AVR MCU is malfunctioning due to 5VDC line surge."_ Please don't. Measure instead (which you have). :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to filter out that ringing noise by some form of decoupling.

---

Solution 1

I suggest you to get:

1. A set of ferrite cores
2. A set of high capacitance electrolytic capacitors
3. A set of ceramic capacitors

Design or copy a filter on the power supply 13 V

Use ceramic capacitors to filter the the VDD of your microcontroller.

---

Solution 2

Buy an isolated DC/DC converters that you put between the factory power supply and your board.

https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/t/traco-power/ten-wirh-railway-industrial-dc-dc-converters

https://www.digikey.com/en/supplier-centers/traco-power

https://www.google.com/search?q=digikey+isolated+DC+dc+converter&client=firefox-b-d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiF0dGQ-Jz0AhWdhP0HHdaIAAIQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1920&bih=899&dpr=1

Answer (score 0):

Why not make your own passive low pass filter?
Although the components are kind of expensive, since you would need capacitors with large capacitances, and resistors capable of large currents. Please do look into filters that use inductors instead of resistors though.
[image]
Image taken from https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_2.html